How can I persist Django session across multiple applications?
I want to be upfront with you the project I'm working with is kind of a mess, so I'm just looking for solutions.
I have a Django app (no DRF) and a CI4 app. I want authentication to persist across the two apps. Basically, the CI4 app is the main, and that's where the user authenticates. I want to use request. Session in the Django app to handle the authentication state.
I made the CI4 app sends a POST request to the Django app, and create a request. Session upon a successful authentication.
@csrf_exempt 
def login_view_endpoint(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        
        user = Utilisateur.checkuser(username, password)
        if user:
            if 'utilisateur' not in request.session:
                request.session['utilisateur'] = user.id
                print(request.session['utilisateur'])
            return HttpResponse('true')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('false')
    else:
        # If the request method is not POST, redirect to the login page
        return HttpResponse('false')

But the issue is when I test the flow of what I had in mind, I get redirected to the "login_page" of my Django app (which I'm trying to remove), which means the session doesn't exist, but the authentication was a success because I got a true response in my CI4 app.
Maybe my understanding of session is lacking, or I'm missing something, or the method doesn't work altogether, I don't know.
I tried asking chatGPT, reading docs and stuff but no solutions. I figured I needed to get someone who have a better understanding of the topic to help me.
I'm aware that it's a very roundabout way and absolutely not safe nor optimized method. But I'm just trying to get it to work for now. Thank you

you have multiple domains with different databases and you want people to login with the same username and password right?

I have multiple domains, but both are using the same database. I want people to just login in the CI4 app, and have the Django app recognize that user.
